# Append objects in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

In my react native app, i stored an object locally and retrieved it, worked fine but now i wanted to append an another object to previous object, like i have two objects:

```
    const obj1 = {key1: keyone, key2: keytwo}
    const obj2 = {key4: keyfour, key6: keysix}
```

All i want back is an object as

```
    { key1: keyone, key2: keytwo }, { key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }
```

and im trying to do it as:

```
    const newVal = `${obj1}, ${obj2}`
```

which returns "object Object"

I went through Object.assign() and also through lodash's .merge() functionality but it seems to be they are merging common fields in object.

How do i acheive this?

Comment: Object need to have key but your desire output is not. Maybe you want array of objects?

Comment: `{ key1: keyone, key2: keytwo }, { key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }` this is not an object.

Comment: `const arr = []; arr.push(obj1); arr.push(obj2);`

Comment: Your `newVal` example is using a "template string" to produce a string variable. So if you want to produce some composite object, then that is not going to work.

Comment: @DavidWinder, as i didnt got anything like i seeked for finally im doing it with array of objects

Comment: @Titus, i was still wondering is there any way to do so in es6 or latest es7, i didnt got anything like that at all

Comment: @ShaileshRathod, im doing it that way, thanks!

Comment: @ManojYadav use array and push objects on it as suggested by Shailesh

Comment: @TimKlein, that means after string interpolation i wont get composite objects back??

Comment: @NirajKaushal, yes right now the best way i can use that

Comment: Correct. After *string* interpolation you will get a *string* back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1. If you want to have an array of objects then you can use this approach:**

```
const arr = [obj1, obj2];
```

it will provide you with the following result:

```
[{ key1: keyone, key2: keytwo }, { key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }]
```

**2. If you want to have the object of objects then you can try this:**

```
const arr = {obj1, obj2};
```

this lead to following result:

```
{ obj1: { key1: keyone, key2: keytwo }, obj2: { key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }}
```

**3. If you want a single object you can try this:**

```
const arr = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

will produce the following result:

```
 { key1: keyone, key2: keytwo, key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }
```

Comment: I believe your second example is wrong. The result would be:

{ obj1: { key1: keyone, key2: keytwo }, obj2: { key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }}

Comment: very rare and awesome explaination, thank you got crystal clear

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread operator (`...`)

```js
const obj1 = {key1: 1, key2: 2};
const obj2 = {key4: 4, key6: 6};

const newVal = {...obj1, ...obj2 };

console.log(newVal);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to merge but instead he wants something like this `{ key1: keyone, key2: keytwo }, { key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }`

Answer (score 1):

You have an object `A = {"a": 1, "b": 2}` and an object `B = {"c": 3, "d": 4}`. You want an object `C` that **contains both as individual objects** (hence the syntax in your question):

`var C = {A, B}; //{{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"c": 3, "d": 4}}`

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is an Object itself containing two objects without keys, my suggestion would be to output an Array of objects which somewhat results to your output.

```
[obj1, obj2] = [{ key1: keyone, key2: keytwo }, { key4: keyfour, key6: keysix }]
```